# How to set custom Metadata on Amazon PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3, metadata, content-type

I tried:

```php
$objS3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $sBucket
    'Key'        => $sBucketFolder . $sFilenameToSave,
    'SourceFile' => $sFile,
    'ACL'        => 'public-read'
    'Metadata'   => [
        'Content-Type'      => 'text/css',
        'Content-Encoding'  => 'gzip', 
    ]
));
```

But it did not work. Any idea?

Tks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContentType` and `ContentEncoding` should not be sent as metadata. Use this instead:

```
$objS3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'          => $sBucket
    'Key'             => $sBucketFolder . $sFilenameToSave,
    'SourceFile'      => $sFile,
    'ACL'             => 'public-read',
    'ContentType'     => 'text/css',
    'ContentEncoding' => 'gzip'
));
```